# how to change the date format using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a input date field whose value is in this "2014-06-07 07:14"(year-month-date hour:minute) format how can i change it to 06/07/2014 07/14( mm/dd/yy) format using jquery.

Comment: Take a look at [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)

Comment: why would someone downvote this? Completely valid question

Comment: is the first date a string? and the second a date object?

Comment: look at this library https://github.com/minagabriel/dtmFRM this library do the exact same thing as C# .tostring() date time format

Comment: Yes please let me know you it is down voted. is it only because i am new to jquery?

Comment: @SamCreamer both are string.

Comment: @p.s.w.g let me try the same thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DateFormat originalFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm", Locale.ENGLISH);
DateFormat targetFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyt hh/mm");
Date date = originalFormat.parse("2014-06-07 07:14");
String formattedDate = targetFormat.format(date);  // 06/07/2014 07/14
```

Docs of [SimpleDateFormat#format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#format%28java.util.Date,%20java.lang.StringBuffer,%20java.text.FieldPosition%29)

PS: A JavaScript implementation of the `format()` method of Java's `SimpleDateFormat`: is available [here](http://www.timdown.co.uk/code/simpledateformat.phphttp://www.timdown.co.uk/code/simpledateformat.php)

Answer (score 2):

Why using jQuery to do this ?

Use plain js:

```
var date = new Date('2014-06-07 07:14');
alert((date.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + date.getDate() + '/' +  date.getFullYear() + ' ' +          date.getHours() + '/' + date.getMinutes());
```

http://jsfiddle.net/F4nq8/

It seems that IE and Safari have some bug with YYYYMMDD dates so a workaround could be something like:

```
var s = "2014-06-07 07:14";
var t = s.split(" ");
var d = t[0].split("-");
var x = d[1] + "/" + d[2] + "/" + d[0] + " " + t[1];
var date = new Date(x);
alert((date.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + date.getDate() + '/' +      date.getFullYear() + ' ' + date.getHours() + '/' + date.getMinutes());
```

http://jsfiddle.net/F4nq8/4/

Some reference about this behaviour: http://biostall.com/javascript-new-date-returning-nan-in-ie-or-invalid-date-in-safari

Comment: @user3341149 have you checked the jsfiddle link in the description ?

Comment: Even if var date = new Date('2014-06-07 07:14');
console.log(date); saying invalid date.

Comment: What browser,version are you using ?

Comment: Still not working on firefox. please check the below answer its working fine.